# Add values from one table to another table with specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL server. I need to create a column in Table2 (ObjectName) and add the itemname values from Table1 into Table2 where the id, teamid, employeeid, and day are all equal.
This is the code I have, but after it executes, there is no change to ObjectName in Table2. I have example tables to show Table1, Table2, and the NewTable I want. itemname in Table1 is datatype nvarchar(50).

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD ObjectName nvarchar(50) Null;

UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.ObjectName = 
    (
        SELECT itemaname
        FROM Table1
        WHERE Table2.Id = Table1.id and Table2.TeamId = Table1.teamid and Table2.EmployeeId = Table1.employeeid and Table2.Day = Table1.day
    );
```

Table1

| id | itemname | teamid | employeeid | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 67 | Cup | 1 | 21 | 1 |
| 69 | Hat | 2 | 45 | 1 |

Table2

| Id | ObjectName | TeamId | EmployeeId | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | Null | 2 | 12 | 1 |
| 67 | Null | 1 | 21 | 1 |
| 67 | Null | 1 | 33 | 1 |
| 69 | Null | 2 | 45 | 1 |

NewTable

| Id | ObjectName | TeamId | EmployeeId | Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63 | Null | 2 | 12 | 1 |
| 67 | Cup | 1 | 21 | 1 |
| 67 | Null | 1 | 33 | 1 |
| 69 | Hat | 2 | 45 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join.

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.ObjectName = table1.itemname
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1
ON Table2.Id = Table1.id 
and Table2.TeamId = Table1.teamid 
and Table2.EmployeeId = Table1.employeeid 
and Table2.Day = Table1.day
```

Comment: I get the error Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "Table2.ObjectName" could not be bound.

Comment: In your diagram, you list a column of Table2 as "ObjectName'.  But SQL is saying that that is not the actual name of the column.